# Numpy savetxt to a string

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to load the result of numpy.savetxt into a string. Essentially the following code without the intermediate file:

```
import numpy as np

def savetxts(arr):
    np.savetxt('tmp', arr)
    with open('tmp', 'rb') as f:
        return f.read()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) (or cStringIO):

> This module implements a file-like class, StringIO, that reads and writes a string buffer (also known as memory files).

The description of the module says it all. Just pass an instance of `StringIO` to `np.savetxt` instead of a filename:

```
>>> s = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> np.savetxt(s, (1,2,3))
>>> s.getvalue()
'1.000000000000000000e+00\n2.000000000000000000e+00\n3.000000000000000000e+00\n'
>>>
```

Comment: As mentioned by @Tom-pohl,  It does not work with `StringIO` but it works with `BytesIO` using python3. Do you have an idea about why it does not work ?

Comment: @Ger Sorry, I have not much experience with python3.

Answer (score 10):

For **Python 3.x** you can use the `io` module:

```
>>> import io
>>> s = io.BytesIO()
>>> np.savetxt(s, (1, 2, 3), '%.4f')
>>> s.getvalue()
b'1.0000\n2.0000\n3.0000\n'

>>> s.getvalue().decode()
'1.0000\n2.0000\n3.0000\n'
```

Note: I couldn't get `io.StringIO()` to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at array_str or array_repr: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.io.html

Comment: By default, both functions shorten their output which is typically not what you want. You can tweak their output using `numpy.set_printoptions`, but that feels like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Just requires extending previous answers with decode to UTF8 in order to generate a string. Very useful for exporting data to human readable text files.

```
import io
import numpy as np

s = io.BytesIO()

np.savetxt(s, np.linspace(0,10, 30).reshape(-1,3), delim=',' '%.4f')
outStr = s.getvalue().decode('UTF-8')
```